# Creating data table in Google Earth Engine

Tags: google-earth-engine

I want to create a data table which has only two column, parameters and value, i want to get feature properties from table1 and add properties and values to table, then print to console...

[GEE Code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/42aa0623c39929cbbf280576cd178711)

```
  var table1 =ee.Feature(
          ee.Geometry.Polygon(
              [[[27.198675268206312, 41.28337381424559],
                [27.198675268206312, 41.186296803350956],
                [27.379949682268812, 41.186296803350956],
                [27.379949682268812, 41.28337381424559]]], null, false),
          {
            "system:index": "0",
            "polID": 123,
            "area": 154,
            "perimeter": 200
          });
          
  print(table1)
  
  table1.evaluate(function(dataTableClient) {
        var per= ee.Number(table1.get('perimeter'))
        var area1 =ee.Number(table1.get('area'))
        
        var dataTable = [
          ['Parameter', 'Value'],
          ['polygon_ID', 123],
          ['perimeter', per],
          ['area', area1],
        ];
        
        var chart = ui.Chart(dataTable).setChartType('Table').setOptions({
          title: 'Parcel Characteristics)',
        });
        print(chart)
  });
```

When i try this code, it gives NAN values... How could be correct these values?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

They way you set up your example the perimeter and area are GEE server-side objects and your plot is client side so you need to get the values from the server with `getInfo()`:

```
        var per= ee.Number(table1.get('perimeter')).getInfo()
        var area1 =ee.Number(table1.get('area')).getInfo()
```

Be carefull with getInfo in your workflow as it is generally not recommended to use!

https://code.earthengine.google.com/1095f8a20034dec80d7c424f3091e054

Answer (score 1):

I found a simpler code, it can be adapted for two columns tables([GEE Code](https://code.earthengine.google.com/c55bd238636ad966615dfb313ac8cf27)):

```
  var table1 =ee.Feature(
          ee.Geometry.Polygon(
              [[[27.198675268206312, 41.28337381424559],
                [27.198675268206312, 41.186296803350956],
                [27.379949682268812, 41.186296803350956],
                [27.379949682268812, 41.28337381424559]]], null, false),
          {
            "system:index": "0",
            "polID": 123,
            "area": 154,
            "perimeter": 200
          });
          
  print(table1)
  
  var Dict = table1.toDictionary()
  var keys = ee.List(Dict.keys())
  var values=ee.List(Dict.values())
  
  var zipped = keys.zip(values)
  
  // Define column names and properties for the DataTable. The order should
  // correspond to the order in the construction of the 'row' property above.
  var columnHeader = ee.List([[
    {label: 'Parameter', role: 'data', type: 'string'},
    {label: 'Value', role: 'data', type: 'string'},
  ]]);
  
  // Concatenate the column header to the table.
  var dataTableServer = columnHeader.cat(zipped);

  // Use 'evaluate' to transfer the server-side table to the client, define the
  // chart and print it to the console.
  dataTableServer.evaluate(function(dataTableClient) {
                var chart = ui.Chart(dataTableClient)
                .setChartType('Table')
                .setOptions({ title: 'Polygon Characteristics)'});
                print(chart)
  });
```